# How can I find the derivative of $(-1)e^{0.1t}+(25-t)\cdot 0.1e^{0.1t}$

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to find the derivative of the function for quite a while but I just can't find it.

Comment: You want derivative of those four terms? And t is variable?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want.

Answer (score 3):

is this $$(-1)e^{0.1t}+(25-t)\cdot 0.1e^{0.1t}$$? if so then we get
$$(-1)e^{0.1t}\cdot 0.1-0.1e^{0.1t}+(25-t)0.1e^{0.1t}\cdot 0.1$$
now you can simplify the derivative. I have use the product and the chaine rule.

Comment: what do you mean?